# Cannot edit EditText when I set visibility to VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-edittext

My `edit text` is currently set to invisible, it is set to visible when my *edit button* is clicked. But when I click the *edit button*, the `EditText` shows but it doesn't let me edit. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code if needed:

```
editPrice.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.kliwa_000.sholocoo.ViewprodsActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:text="PRODUCT"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:text="Edit Price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your edittext xml code here

Comment: add line `editPrice.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: @NikunjPatel okay wait

Comment: @userI it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give `bringToFront`

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editPrice.bringToFront ();
                editPrice.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @justlovly, Welcome

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editPrice.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```